# Why does the Beautiful Soup package not work in my Python project although I used "pip install beautifulsoup4"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, pip

Even though I used [pip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_%28package_manager%29) to install [Beautiful Soup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beautiful_Soup_(HTML_parser)) 4, it still didn't work for me. I used the code `pip install beautifulsoup4` and the system said the installation was successful.

But when I run the program, the system says that *bs4* cannot be found, knowing that my machine has two Python versions: 3.9 (global) and 3.11. The system *pip* belongs to 3.11.

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8S2oN.png)

I have moved my [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code) to Python 3.11, but it’s still not working. How can I fix it? Or is there a way to change the 3.9 (global) version of the machine to 3.11?

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPs72.png)

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mre] instead of images of code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use 'py' instead of 'python' to run the command.

'py' refers to the Python launcher, which automatically uses the latest Python version installed in your environment.
You can also specify the version like this 'py -3.11'.

For example, I have 3.10.10 and 3.11.2 installed on my PC.

The result (on Windows):

```
python --version
```

> `Python 3.10.10`

```
py --version
```

> `Python 3.11.2`

```
py -3.11 --version
```

> `Python 3.11.2`